# Google DFP doesn't find lib in Titanium

Tags: java, android, admob, titanium-modules

I want to use admob in Appcelerator Titanium. I add `google-play-services.jar` into the Java module.

The jar route is

> /Library/android-sdk-macosx/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/

I haven't got any error from any import. I don't understand what is happening.

But when I compile the module this error appear:

```
[javac] Compiling 3 source files to /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/build/classes
       [javac] /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/src/ti/admob/AdmobModule.java:15: package com.google.android.gms.common does not exist
       [javac] import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
       [javac]                                     ^
       [javac] /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/src/ti/admob/View.java:16: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
       [javac] import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/src/ti/admob/View.java:17: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
       [javac] import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/src/ti/admob/View.java:18: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
       [javac] import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/src/ti/admob/View.java:19: package com.google.android.gms.ads does not exist
       [javac] import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
       [javac]                                  ^
       [javac] /Users/acavero/Documents/Titanium_Studio_Workspace/android-admob/android/src/ti/admob/View.java:20: package com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob does not exist
       [javac] import com.google.android.gms.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobExtras;
```

Libraries I have:

[image]

Comment: No, I have the correct path sorry. I forgot put /google-play-services.jar. I add the library in Module->Properties->AddExternals JARs...

Comment: Take #2 - Have you looked at this:  https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup ?  It looks like you should be adding Google Play services via a library ... not by adding individual JAR files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:** I solved this copying the `google_play_services.jar` directly at project